# Clipboard inconsistent between applications

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, clipboard

I'm running OSX 10.10 and I have issues when trying to copy between applications. I find that I seem to have at least 2 clipboards. One for

- Adium
- Automator
- Calculator
- Calendar
- Contacts
- Cyberduck
- Dashboard
- Dictionary
- Google Chrome
- TextMate
- PyCharm
- Dropbox
- ClipMenu
- `pbcopy`/`pbpaste`
- Safari
- Sonos

Another for:

- iTerm2
- Sticky Notes
- Slack
- Spotlight
- Finder (Edit -> show clipboard)

I'm not sure which is the system clipboard, and it's incredibly annoying not to be able to copy between applications effectively. Has anyone experienced this before? What can I do about it?

**EDIT: I had had chrome in the wrong category. I moved it.**

**EDIT 2: I started going through my applications alphabetically. I've added a bunch more to the top category.**

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature, MacOS doesn't have double clipboard =) Apart from joke, are you sure you have no malware? Some bad malware can hijack/change clipboard content consistently and are known to cause such issues.

Comment: can you give a more detailed step by step example of copying between `Dropbox` and `Sticky Notes`. This is needed, because the apps `pbcopy/pbpaste` and `Safari` are OSX standard, same as `Sticky Notes`, which makes it impossible to re-produce your answered behaviour unless we know what you did exactly.

Comment: I take a screenshot, at which point Dropbox stores it and copies a dropbox link to my clipboard. I then paste in stickies and paste the thing that I copied in stickies before dropbox affected my keyboard. If I paste in Chrome or Safari (command+V), then it pastes the dropbox link. If I paste in iTerm or Slack (command + V), it pastes what I copied in stickies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing ClipMenu? It looks like the project has not been updated to support Yosemite: https://github.com/naotaka/ClipMenu/issues/8#issuecomment-109988640

Also, you can see which group of applications is using the Mac Clipboard with Finder -> Edit -> Show Clipboard.

**Final Solution:**
`launchctl list | grep com.apple.pboard` to check the existence of the pboard daemon (This should spit it out). Then:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.pboard
launchctl start com.apple.pboard
```

Then kill an application on the bad list, relaunch it, and see if it starts working on the good list.

Comment: I added clipMenu to try to deal with this problem. :-\

Comment: So what happens when you remove ClipMenu? What about Finder -> Edit -> Show Clipboard?

Comment: I removed clipmenu and the problem persists. I added finder to one of the categories above.

Comment: Execute the following command from terminal:

`cat /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pboard.plist | pbcopy`

and paste the results here.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jake223/e11725a39c20b19dd4a1#file-gistfile1-txt - (I had to copy only the command and do `\`pbpaste\` | pbcopy`, :p)

Comment: `launchctl list | grep com.apple.pboard` to check the existence of the pboard daemon (This should spit it out).

Then try: `launchctl stop com.apple.pboard` and then `launchctl start com.apple.pboard`

Then kill an application on the bad list, relaunch it, and see if it starts working on the good list.

Comment: If you edit your answer to be your most recent comment and add that I should also restart an application on the good list to get it onto the new clipboard, I'll accept and upvote your answer (and bounty it if this works for a few days)

Comment: Updated my original post.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this who does not find himself with a duplicate apple board (using the list command). This also happens for me after a random amount of time (usually after a couple of days) on High Sierra. A full reboot always restores the intended functionality for me. It seems as if putting the device to hibernate often enough will at some point break your clipboard management. I haven't digged into that further but I hope it helps!